# Cannot invoke 'UTTypeEqual' with an argument list of type '(CFString!, CFString!)'

Tags: string, swift, types, nsstring, cfstring

How do I get this to compile?

On the second line of this function:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! CFString!
    if UTTypeEqual(mediaType, kUTTypeJPEG) {
        println("jpg")
    }
}
```

I get the compilation error:

```
Cannot invoke 'UTTypeEqual' with an argument list of type '(CFString!, CFString!)'
```

Comment: Snarky aside: to get this to compile, you can just delete this code. The question you mean is "how do I compare two UTIs?" (OK, now on to actually answering the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITypeEqual` returns `Boolean`, not `Bool`. The easiest way to deal with `Boolean` is to compare it to 0.

```
    if UTTypeEqual(mediaType, kUTTypeJPEG) != 0 {
```